# SQL Server Get one row for each student with highest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have two tables as follows:
[image]

I want to find the StudentId, FirstName, StudentLoginInfoId, LoginDate. I am expecting only one entry per student with higher LoginDate.

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: What are you having issues with? Can you share your code that is not producing the expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We would like to assist but instead of just providing an answer we would like to know what you have tried (IE - what SQL query/queries have you tried, what is the result(s) and what are you not understanding with those results and/or what errors are you getting. (especially on something that looks like homework).  It enables all of us to better assist and help with your learning journey. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to number output of the result-set for each partition (here each student) in a subquery and achieve your desired output by applying a condition of the number assigned for each student to be 1 which will equal one row.

```
select studentid, firstname, studentlogininfoid, logindate
from (
  select 
    s.studentid, s.firstname, sl.studentlogininfoid, sl.logindate, 
    row_number() over (partition by sl.studentid order by sl.logindate desc) as rn
  from student s
  inner join studentlogininfoid sl on s.studentid = sl.studentid
) t
where rn = 1
```

Explaining arguments for `row_number`:

- `PARTITION BY` specifies what are your groups to enumerate separately (start from 1 for each group)
- `ORDER BY` specifies how should rows be enumerated (based on which order)

If we enumerate rows for each student and sort them from latest date descending, then the first row for each student (the row with `rn = 1`) will contain highest login date value for that student.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "CROSS APPLY" to find what you want:

```
SELECT    S.StudentId
        , S.FirstName
        , SLI.StudentLoginInfoId
        , SLI.LoginDate 
FROM Student S
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM StudentLoginInfo SLI WHERE S.StudentId = SLI.StudentId ORDER BY LoginDate DESC) SLI
```